# Android: How to poll email?

Tags: java, android, email, android-intent, widget

I'm making a widget who, among other things, displays the quantity of unread emails the user has in a given inbox. 

Specifically, I'm asking how to:

-Obtain the list of email accounts on the device

-Make a call to one of the accounts such as

```
    int newMailCount = accountInstance.getMailCount()
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Obtain the list of email accounts on the device

This is not possible. You can use `AccountManager` to try to get at account information, but there is no "email" type that I am aware of, and email programs do not have to use `AccountManager`.

> Make a call to one of the accounts

There is nothing in the Android SDK for email. There are dozens, perhaps hundreds, of email programs out there. None are part of the operating system. Email programs are welcome to create their own app widgets.